# Bash scripting, using arrow keys

Tags: bash

```
getchar() {
trap "" SIGINT SIGQUIT
trap "return;" $SIG_DEAD
while true; do
    read -s -n 1 key
    case "$key" in
        [qQ]) kill -$SIG_QUIT $game_pid
              return
              ;;
        [kK]) kill -$SIG_UP $game_pid
              ;;
        [lL]) kill -$SIG_RIGHT $game_pid
              ;;
        [jJ]) kill -$SIG_DOWN $game_pid
              ;;
        [hH]) kill -$SIG_LEFT $game_pid
              ;;
   esac
done
}
```

I have this part of a code and the values in `[]` are for moving wright, left, up and down. I would like to replace it with the arrrows on the keyboard, but i don´t know what value to put in.

Comment: Found the answer [A - UP ;
    [B - DN ;
    [D - LEFT ;
    [C - RIGHT ;

Comment: You can found the answer here, i tested it and it works for me:              https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179191/bashscript-to-detect-right-arrow-key-being-pressed